# Any way to append existing Java List content with elements of other List without copying

Tags: java, memory-management, containers

**PROBLEM**

I currently have 2 `java.util.ArrayList` instances visible through `java.util.List` interface. I want to append all elements of one list to another one. I don't care about source list (`l2`) anymore. And I do care about memory, object life cycle, garbage collector and overall performance.

So what I have:

```
List<X> l1 = new ArrayList<X>(); // .... bla-bla-bla
List<X> l2 = new ArrayList<X>(); // .... bla-bla-bla
```

Now I can do:

```
l1.addAll(l2);
l2.clear();
```

Looks like it should provoke faster `l2` cleanup what is desired effect. But what about complexity?

---

**QUESTION**

Ideally I'd like to receive something better like

```
l1.moveSomeReference(l2);
```

And have `l1` containing `l2` elements added and `l2` emptied with minimal complexity.

**Is it possible? If yes, how?**

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

- The aim is to reduce object life cycle for GC.
- Both `l1` and `l2` are encapsulated into objects, objects are coming as a parameters for a method. So just assignment with `null` is actually possible but not so wanted.
- It is possible to change container. Keeping `List` interface is preferable.

Comment: Is this code contained in a single method; that is, are these lists only used in one method, populated there, and returned somewhere eventually?

Comment: They are coming from outside as a parameters and I know I don't need them anymore, only result of merge. And this is why I cannot do things like l2 = null, no sense.

Comment: About how many elements are in each of these lists before merging?

Comment: They could be pretty small, but there is HUGE amount of them.

Comment: The aim is to show them as 'empty' for GC. If it is possible, reducing copy.

Comment: First, I would suggest that you profile your application to determine if this is actually a problem or if you only think there is/will be a problem. Second, if there is a measurable problem, rather than having a "HUGE amount of [Lists]" you might consider utilizing one of the other types in the Collection family or rolling your own data structure specifically tuned for your needs.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I have measured. This merge takes significant part from the memory point of view. Application is distributed so sharp profiling is not possible. Too much noise around.

Comment: amount of data is really HUGE - about 17G of compressed data in small objects.

Comment: There may be more factors at play here.  Merely removing one reference wouldn't reduce the amount of memory being used (potentially) unless there are a ton of duplicates across lists.  Something tells me that's not the case, as even `addAll` only makes shallow copies (moves references, not whole objects).  Further, you can't guarantee when GC runs anyway, so that reference may not get cleaned up.  I'm concerned that you may be addressing a symptom of a bigger problem; it seems like you may be bringing back too much data to work with in the first place.

Comment: This looks like it might help you to some extent? http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29